# sql server queries role based access control as a view

Tags: sql-server

My apology in advance. There may already be an answer on the web, but I am not sure what keyword am I supposed to search for.

I have created the following database designs for role-based access control where:

### **role table**

```
role_id (pk)
role_name
```

### **permission table**

```
permission_id (pk)
permission
```

### **role_permission table:**

```
role_permission_id (pk)
role_id (fk from role table)
perm_id (fk from permission table)
edit_perm (this is bit if 1 can edit)
view_perm (this is bit if 1 can view)
```

My goal is to have a select queries as such:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpevw.png

is there anyway of achieving this?

I am very confused. I greatly appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: best option is to use Dynamic SQL

Comment: The db looks ok, You have to query the db to see what part are enable in your UI. What is the problem?

Comment: I am not too sure how to do select queries to have all the roles as rows whereas permissions as the columns. I don't think the group by is the solution. Would sub-query be the right choice?

Comment: or do I do the inner join on role table and role-permission table?

Comment: If you want pure SQL solution pivot may be options. Other wise do inner join in query and use two loops in your view outer loop for roles and inner for permission